# OR and AND operator confusion in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, operators, logical-operators

I was coding along Colt Steele's Web developer bootcamp. This is the original file [link]  I was confused on line 5, while loop on line 5 continues as long as we don't type "quit" or "q". It requires only one thing "quit" or "q" to close the loop, when I type either "quit" or "q" loop closes. Only one thing to close the loop ("quit" or "q") But I read that AND need both conditions in order to be true. Isn't it ? And when I use || instead of && it behaves oddly. Can anyone explain plz? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this because it contains what is essentially advertisement that has no bearing on the actual question.

Comment: Actually I am a newbie, can you help me with the answer?

Comment: I would suggest studying up on boolean logic & deMorgan's laws, as linked below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps you to understand, you can rewrite it from AND to OR:

```
while (command != "quit" && command != "q") {
  // do job
}
```

is equivalent to

```
while (!(command === "quit" || command === "q")) {
  // do job
}
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: Thanks! so I need to learn De Morgan law ?

Comment: From what I understand. When command is not equal to "quit" (command != "quit") it is true, and when command is not equal to "q" (command != "q") it is also true. So loop runs. When any of the command changes to "quit" or "q". It becomes false, even if one is false, and loop stops right ?

Comment: You don't have to learn it, but knowing some boolean algebra would help you with programming. The code is infinite loop, stopping only when command is "q" or "quit" (but it can never be both). If you replace AND with OR in original code, the loop become unstoppable, because any value will satisfy first or second condition.

Comment: oh right, is my second comment right or wrong ? thank you! you really helped me btw.

Comment: yes, you got it right :)

Answer (score 0):

When `command` is **not** `q` and command is **not** `quit` do something.

So `command` can be everything except `quit` and `q`

If you would use **or** it would mean

When `command` is **not** `q` or `command` is **not** `quit` do something.

So now when `command` is `q` it's still not `quit` so the loop is still going and vice versa

From [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) we know that

> The negation of a disjunction is the conjunction of the negations

So `not q and not quit` is the same as `not (q or quit)`

Comment: The above code is like a mini list app. When we either type "quit" or "q" only one thing not two. The loop on line 5 (while loop) closes.